# JQuery not finishing (repeating animation instead)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone explain why my `.close` click function isn't completing, but rather just getting nearly finished and bouncing back to it's original state before close button is clicked?

Opening the menu works just fine, So I tried to essentially remove all css classes and do everything backwards but it doesn't seem to be working; I've recreated the basic problem here; http://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/MvQsT/1507/

Here's my JS that's being problematic

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      'opacity': '0'
    }, 200);
    $("#project3").animate({
      'height': '50px'
    }, 1500);
    $("#project3").removeClass("cursor-fix");
    $("#project3").removeClass("no-info");
    $("#project3").removeClass("stick-subtitle");
    $(".dark3").removeClass("project-open");
    $(".toggle-more").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element `.close` is inside `#project3` use  `e.stopPropagation()` on `.close` click for resolve your issue.

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/2uth18rq/

```
$(".close").click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).animate({
      'opacity': '0'
    }, 200);
    $("#project3").animate({
      'height': '50px'
    }, 1500);
    $("#project3").removeClass("cursor-fix");
    $("#project3").removeClass("no-info");
    $("#project3").removeClass("stick-subtitle");
    $(".dark3").removeClass("project-open");
    $(".toggle-more").css("display", "none");
  });
```